# How to replace positions that satisfy a predicate "on the fly"?

Tags: r

**NB**: The example below uses the predicate `is.na`, but this is just an example.  I'm interested in the general case.  (IOW, the predicate could be `is.infinite`, or `is.nan`, or anything else.)

---

Suppose some expression `foo(...)` evaluates to a dataframe that may contain some `NA` values in it, and that function `bar` takes a `NA`-free dataframe as argument.

One way to avoid passing an invalid argument to `bar` requires an intermediate assignment:

```
tmp <- foo(...)
tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
bar(tmp)
```

Is there some function `baz` that would allow doing the same thing with

```
bar(baz(foo(...), is.na, 0, ...))
```

...*thereby obviating the need for an intermediate assignment*?

I know that I can always write my own `baz`, but was wondering if anything like it is already available in R.

---

**UPDATE:**

(In response to Frank's comment.)

*Example*

```
x <- data.frame(K=1001:1005,
                I=3:7,
                R=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),
                B=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
                C=c(0.1+0.2i, 0.3+0.4i, 0.5+0.6i, 0.7+0.8i, 0.9+1.0i))

y <- data.frame(K=1001:1003,
                S1=c("a", "b", "c"),
                S2=c("d", "e", "f"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With these definitions, then `foo(...)` could be the expression

```
merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = "K")
```

For `bar`, I suppose the simplest thing would something artificial, like

```
bar <- function (nonas) { stopifnot(!any(is.na(nonas))); nonas }
```

A home-rolled `baz` could be

```
baz <- function (thing, predicate, value) {
    thing[predicate(thing)] <- value
    thing
}
```

Then,

```
bar(merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = "K"))
## Error: !any(is.na(nonas)) is not TRUE
bar(baz(merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = "K"), is.na, -1))
##      K I   R     B        C S1 S2
## 1 1001 3 0.1  TRUE 0.1+0.2i  a  d
## 2 1002 4 0.2 FALSE 0.3+0.4i  b  e
## 3 1003 5 0.3  TRUE 0.5+0.6i  c  f
## 4 1004 6 0.4 FALSE 0.7+0.8i -1 -1
## 5 1005 7 0.5  TRUE 0.9+1.0i -1 -1
```

Comment: Could you create an example `tmp` to consider at least? Seems quite possible that the `replace` function might do it...

Comment: @Frank: I added an example to my post.  Also, I don't see how `replace` could avoid the assignment to an intermediate variable (like `tmp` in my post).

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. Your post seems to contain a functioning answer already in `bar(baz(foo(), is.na, 0))` where `foo = function() your code`. You're asking if such a function exists already in some package? Btw, if you dislike both intermediate variables and parentheses, there's `foo() %>% replace(pred(.), 0) %>% bar`

Comment: @Frank: yes, I wanted to know if such function already exists, either in R or in some package.  But your suggestion with `%>%` is just as good (if I could only get it to work!)

Comment: @Frank: OK, I got the `%>%` idea to work.  BTW, do you know of a keyword I could use to search the documentation for the single `.` in `replace(pred(.), 0)`?  I tried `?\`.\``, etc., but got nowhere.

Comment: @Frank: Thank you for the `%>%` suggestion.  Care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid storing the result of `foo()`, one could do

```
library(magrittr)
foo() %>% replace(pred(.), 0) %>% bar
```

This usage is documented in `` ?`%>%` ``:

> **Using the dot for secondary purposes**
>
> Often, some attribute or property of lhs is desired in the rhs call in addition to the value of lhs itself, e.g. the number of rows or columns. It is perfectly valid to use the dot placeholder several times in the rhs call, but by design the behavior is slightly different when using it inside nested function calls. In particular, if the placeholder is only used in a nested function call, lhs will also be placed as the first argument!

Generally, pipes can be slow, so I wouldn't use this for anything too performance-critical. I think OP's helper function `baz` is pretty useful for this case, like `bar(baz(foo(), is.na, 0))`.